# Custom font in Visualforce not working?

Tags: visualforce, css, font

When we load a custom font from CDN or download a custom font and upload it as static resource, it will work.

However we had one handmade font for us which doesn't work for some reason. 
It will work fine with random HTML/CSS page, so the issue is only with Visualforce page displaying it.

Are there some Force.com limitation when it comes to very custom font files?
Everything is in WOFF format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue once, and was able to overcome it by creating a Data URI out of the font file (this is a truetype, but same principle), e.g.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Some-Font';
  src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,BASE64_ENCODED_DATA_HERE) format('truetype')
}
```